# How to obtain the following estimates of $\int_{1}^{t} \frac{ds}{(t-s)^{1/2}s^{\alpha}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

How to obtain the following estimates? ($t$ is positive, of course)
$\int_{1}^{t} \frac{ds}{(t-s)^{1/2}s^{\alpha}}=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\mathcal O (t^{-(\alpha - 1/2)}) &,\alpha<1 \\ 
\mathcal O (t^{ - 1/2} \ln t) &, \alpha  = 1\\ 
\mathcal O (t^{- 1/2}) &, \alpha >1\\
\end{array} 
\right.$
So far, I tried substitution which seems an obvious choice: $\int_{1}^{t} \frac{ds}{(t-s)^{1/2}s^{\alpha}}=\frac{1}{t^{\alpha - 1/2}}\int_{1/t}^{1} \frac{ds}{(1-s)^{1/2}s^{\alpha}}$

Next, I think I should estimate the integrand around $s=0$ but can't proceed. I appreciate any help and answers.

Comment: But $s=0$ is not in the domain of integration. so why do you  need  such estimate

Comment: @GuyFsone It's a problem in a real analysis book and the author claims it's obivous.

Comment: I you can see that in $s=0$ the integrand is equivalent to $s^{-\alpha} $